# Adjective that describes "boosting one's ego"?

Tags: single-word-requests

Example:

> Being one of a kind is [...], but lonely at times."

Maybe uplifting? I'm looking for something less formal, though.

Comment: Uplifting is not formal, it's perfectly fine and fits really well in that sentence. Otherwise consider: awesome, amazing, unique (one of a kind), intoxicating, mind-blowing,...

Comment: @Mari-LouA  It’s true, now that you mention it, that “UPlifting” works very well here with “lonely.”  I can actually see now how it could serve as a pretty cool veiled reference to what is arguably the ultimate expression of one’s ego: “It’s lonely [UP here] at the top.”

Comment: ...ego-boosting?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
             "Being one of a kind is gratifying, but lonely at times."
```

> **gratify** *verb*; 3rd person present: gratifies; past tense: gratified; past participle: gratified; gerund or present participle: gratifying
>
> give (someone) pleasure or satisfaction. "I was *gratified* to see the coverage in May's issue"
>
> *synonyms*: please, gladden, make happy, delight, make someone feel good, satisfy; see Google [gratify](https://www.google.com/search?sourceid=navclient&aq=&oq=gratify+de&ie=UTF-8&rlz=1T4VRHB_enUS620US620&q=gratify+definition&gs_l=hp..0.0j0i22i30l4.0.0.0.10987...........0.E1PhTnM0rxg&gws_rd=ssl)

Comment: This answer is good. It would be even better for this context if you mentioned *self-gratifying*. The question is about *boosting one's [own] ego*.

Comment: Thanks, @Drew - I guess I thought the "self" part was understood.

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest **"flattering"**.

> flattering (adj)  "pleasing or gratifying the vanity of"
>
> - "What really flatters a man is that you think him worth flattering" (George Bernard Shaw).
> - "It was flattering to be told how indispensable he was."  [TFD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/flattering)

Answer (score 3):

Probably no less formal then “uplifting,” but “[laudable](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/laudable?s=t)” would perhaps also work, as would any of its synonyms, such as "[commendable](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/commendable?s=t)," “[praiseworthy](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/praiseworthy),” or “[prideworthy](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/prideworthy).”

(Just an afterthought, but to the extent that the above suggestions are still a bit too formal, the ‘simple’ word “great” [or just “good,” depending on how high you want to boost the ego] could work nicely, especially in your specific example to emphasize the frustrating contrast with the fairly well-known “it's/that’s great, but …” construction.)

Answer (score 1):

Ego and pride are somewhat similar, sometimes conflated. Based on that, I looked for a word which means to boost one's pride. Depending on the actual idea you're trying to express, one of these might be helpful:

Being one of a kind _ _, but lonely at times.

is exalting/exalts

is glorifying/glorifies
is aggrandizing
is dignifying
is ennobling
is an honour

Also, this site might be helpful: http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/exalting

Answer (score 0):

"Being one of a kind is *sublime*, but lonely at times."

Definition of [sublime](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/sublime) from Dictionary.com:

> impressing the mind with a sense of grandeur or power; inspiring awe, veneration, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just "ego-boosting"...?

https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/ego-boost